# Stating constant arrays value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

For example I have:

```
int boo[8];
boo[1] = boo[3] = boo[7] = 4;
boo[0] = boo[2] = 7;
boo[4] = boo[5] = boo[6] = 15;
```

How I should type it as constant values? I saw similar question but it didn't help me.

EDIT:
One more question what about if boo with indexes 0 1 3 4 5 6 7 is constant but boo[2] is not? is it possible to do it?

Comment: If by "constant values" you mean an initialization list, you can't. But some compilers provide interesting extensions. Take a look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

Comment: Do you mean you want const int boo[8] ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
const int boo[] = { 7, 4, 7, 4, 15, 15, 15, 4 };
```

Get a non-const pointer to one entry in the array like this:

```
int * foo = (int*)&boo[2];
```

Comment: Yes, one more question what about if boo with index 0 1 3 4 5 6 7 is constants but boo[2] is not?

Comment: Maybe you can access it via a different pointer: int const* boo2 = boo+2;

And after *boo2 = 5;

Comment: I have modified the answer to include an example of getting a pointer you can use to modify one entry.

Answer (score 3):

One not so elegant solution may be:

```
const int boo[8] = {7,4,7,4,15,15,15,4};
```

Another solution may be:

```
int boo_[8];
boo_[1] = boo_[3] = boo_[7] = 4;
boo_[0] = boo_[2] = 7;
boo_[4] = boo_[5] = boo_[6] = 15;
const int * boo = boo_;
```

Comment: Nah, it seems quite elegant to me :)

Comment: Use `boo_` instead of `_boo`. Names starting with underscores, or double underscores, are reserved for use by the implementation(compiler). There are certain rules here but its probably just best to avoid the underscore at the beginning all together.